# Magento tiered pricing display issue

Tags: price, tierprice, bundle

I have a bundle product, with 10 of the same simple product in, i.e. a 10 pack of SKU.
This is set up as dynamically priced as we need the prices to be written to the `flat_order_item` table for the SKU line, not the bundle line.

I have set up a tier price for 10 in the simple product.

Everything works fine apart from the price in the category listing does not display properly - it displays a price of `10 x the original price`, not the tiered price.

The parameters for the bundled item are set to required, quantity of 10 and ticked as default.

To confirm, the correct price displays on the product view page, but not the category page.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have similar issue but with bundle products and group pricing. When a customer who belongs to that particular group logs in, the correct prices for that group are shown on product page but not on the catalog listing page. It just shows the full price. My bundle products are made up of several simple products each with their own pricing structure, bundle itself is dynamic. Any help appreciated!